# How to check if counter is out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to traverse through a 2d array. I currently have a crossword puzzle set up in a char array and I need to be able to check a letter's surrounding letters to see if the word I'm currently looking for is connected to that first letter. I have boolean methods already set up to do a job I need but I would like to know if there is a way to check if my current counter is out of bounds of my array. My array looks like this:

```
    W V E R T I C A L L 

    R O O A F F L S A B 

    A C R I L I A T O A 

    N D O D K O N W D C 

    D R K E S O O D D K 

    O E E P Z E G L I W 

    M S I I H O A E R A 

    A L R K R R I R E R 

    K O D I D E D R C D 

    H E L W S L E U T H
```

My current code is this:

```
    public static boolean check(int row, int col, String word, char[][] puzzle) {       
    if(checkRight(row, col, word, puzzle)) return true;
    if(checkLeft(row, col, word, puzzle)) return true;
    if(checkUp(row, col, word, puzzle)) return true;
    if(checkDown(row, col, word, puzzle)) return true;
    if(checkNW(row, col, word, puzzle)) return true;
    if(checkNE(row, col, word, puzzle)) return true;
    if(checkSW(row, col, word, puzzle)) return true;
    if(checkSE(row, col, word, puzzle)) return true;
    return false;
}

private static boolean checkRight(int row, int col, String word, char[][] puzzle) {
    //Checking right direction
    for(int letter = 1; letter < word.length(); letter++) {
        if(puzzle[row][col + letter] != word.charAt(letter)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


private static boolean checkLeft(int row, int col, String word, char[][] puzzle) {
    //Checking left direction
    for(int letter = 1; letter < word.length(); letter++) {
        if(puzzle[row + letter][col] != word.charAt(letter)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


private static boolean checkUp(int row, int col, String word, char[][] puzzle) {
    //Checking up direction
    for(int letter = 1; letter < word.length(); letter++) {
        if(puzzle[row - letter][col] != word.charAt(letter)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


private static boolean checkDown(int row, int col, String word, char[][] puzzle) {
    //Checking down direction
    for(int letter = 1; letter < word.length(); letter++) {
        if(puzzle[row][col - letter] != word.charAt(letter)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


private static boolean checkSE(int row, int col, String word, char[][] puzzle) {
    //Checking diagonals direction
    for(int letter = 1; letter < word.length(); letter++) {
        if(puzzle[row + letter][col + letter] != word.charAt(letter) && <row<) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


private static boolean checkSW(int row, int col, String word, char[][] puzzle) {
    //Checking diagonals direction
    for(int letter = 1; letter < word.length(); letter++) {
        if(puzzle[row + letter][col - letter] != word.charAt(letter)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean checkNW(int row, int col, String word, char[][] puzzle) {
    //Checking diagonals direction
    for(int letter = 1; letter < word.length(); letter++) {
        if(puzzle[row - letter][col - letter] != word.charAt(letter)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean checkNE(int row, int col, String word, char[][] puzzle) {
    //Checking diagonals direction
    for(int letter = 1; letter < word.length(); letter++) {
        if(puzzle[row - letter][col + letter] != word.charAt(letter)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: Instead of having 8 functions, you can just have 1 where you pass the change in `row` and change in `col` (something like `puzzle[row + rowChange*letter][col + colChange*letter]`).

Comment: `My array looks like this:` If you use a matrix you can use puzzle.length for rows and puzzle[].length for columns.. so to answer your question. You can prevent out of bounds if you use an index in range from 0 to length-1, so for your loops you can use array.length istead of a counter that doesn't guarantee to be the real size.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the dimensions of 2D array?

Comment: You could add the check to the for loops end condition.  As in "for (int letter = 1; letter < word.length() && row + letter < puzzle.length; letter++)".  But wouldn't it be better to just find all the words in the puzzle in one shot, rather than checking over and over?

Comment: @Dukeling How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @DevOfZot I am a super noob when it comes to java. How can I get it to find all the words in 1 go?

Comment: Well, if you have a dictionary and the puzzle doesn't change at runtime, you could just pre-process it - look through the puzzle beforehand, check every string and find all the words, and store them in a list or something, and just check the list.  But I don't know what the application is supposed to do so this may not make sense.

Comment: If you don't want to bother with the four checks row,col <0 or >=length, consider declaring the array with one extra space on each side, filled with a special value like null or " ". Then it's one uniform check.

Comment: @Dukeling How would I make it go through the different directions through. Wouldn't I still need 8 functions to tell it that to check a diagonal direction is row+1, col+1, etc...?

Comment: @clwhisk I tried that but couldn't figure out how to add a " " character to a pre-existing array or make the loop to build it before hand. One thought I had was to create an array with the dimensions I need+2. Then on the very edge of the array like a border, having that null or " " character but I can't figure out how to read in my letters and fill in the middle blanks.

Comment: @Drieke That was the suggestion, to increase the dimensions by 2. Then it's the same as before, only your data starts at (1,1). Must have put your data in an array once already, but if shaky you should review the basics from some book or [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a generic function that work for every direction. That is, to the current position you calculate the position of your neightbors by adding an `offsetx` and `offsety` that are in range `[-1,1]`. Look at this code that do pretty much what you want:

```
//This is your generic-direction function
public static boolean check(int row, int col, String word, char[][] puzzle, int offsetx, int offsety)

    //start with the current position
    int x = row;
    int y = col;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.lenth(); i++){
        //Is not equal
        if (puzzle[x][y] != word.charAt(i)) return false;

        //Calculate the next position
        x += offsetx;
        y += offsety;

        //check the boundaries, if we go out then we didn't find the word;
        if (x < 0 || x >= puzzle.length || y < 0 || y >= puzzle[x].length) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And this is how we call for each direction;

```
//check right
if(check(row, col, word, puzzle, 1, 0)) return true;

//check left
if(check(row, col, word, puzzle, -1, 0)) return true;

//check top
if(check(row, col, word, puzzle, 0, -1)) return true;

...
```

But an easier way is to define the offset in an array, like this

```
//These are the offset you add to the current position
int [] movx ={-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
int [] movy ={-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1};

//this variable will hold if we found or not the string in the puzzle
boolean found = false;

//check all directions
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    //found the string, change the flag 'found' and break
    if(check(row, col, word, puzzle, movx[i], movy[i])){
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

//string not found
if (!found){
    System.out.println("String not found");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So I was able to use what you gave me and I got it to work but there's one glitch that I just can't seem to figure out. I can't figure out where to put a print statement saying that a word cannot be found if it failed all the searches. If I put it anywhere in the loops it just repeats over and over.

Comment: Thanks again! I was able to implement it and make it work! Now I just have to figure out why my loop is skipping some words.

Answer (score 0):

this can be solved by limiting the calls to your checking functions.

For instance:
If the letter you are starting at is not on the far left, you can check for a word to the left, diagonally up and left, and diagonally up and right... since there is nothing left of the letter otherwise. The same applies for the top, bottom, and right.

Additionally, if your puzzle is in char[][] puzzle, puzzle[0].length and puzzle.length will get the dimensions of your puzzle, for use in checking loops etc as an upper bound or starting point.